# Ruby greater than operand weird behaviour

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.1

Can someone please explain me why this can be happening

```
$ irb
2.1.1 :001 > "9" > "3"
 => true 
2.1.1 :002 > "10" > "3"
 => false 
2.1.1 :005 > "2.3" > "2.1"
 => true
2.1.1 :003 >
```

Why is `"10" > "3"` returning false ?

Answer (score 1):

Because in all these cases Strings are compared, not Numbers. And when Strings are compared, it's done character-by-character. Apparently, character `"1"` is 'less' than character `"3"`.

Answer (score 0):

`String` class included `Comparable` module. Thus in each tests, you are performing, actually calling [`Comparable#>`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Comparable.html#method-i-3E) method, which in turn calls [`String#<=>`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) method.

> Why `"10" > "3"` returns `true` ?

First see the doc - *If the strings are of **different** lengths, and the strings are **equal** when compared up to the **shortest** length, then the **longer** string is considered **greater** than the **shorter** one.*

Now in your case, yes, `'10'` and `'3'` are of **different size**. But **the strings are not *equal* when compared up to the *shortest* length**, thus **longer string is not considered *greater* than the *shorter* one.** It means `1` from longer string, is not equal `'3'` from the shortest string. This equality is performed by [`String#eql?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-eql-3F).

Now again consider the example `"10" > '1'`, it return `true`, as **the strings are *equal* when compared up to the *shortest* length**, thus **longer string is considered *greater* than the *shorter* one.**

But when **strings** are having *equal* size, then comparisons are made *character by character*, using `String#eql?` method.